# How to get a dynamic Google map with filtered views and show a marker related to the selected item?

Tags: 7, views, google-maps

I plan to create a real estate agency website. In the front page, users can select the type of contract and specific other things to get a list of all the nodes that fit those criteria. So the result is a view (filtered).

I want to get a Google map with marker related to this result. This is possible, but the thing that I can't do is this: when I select an item from this filtered view (with a checkbox for example) I want to recalculate the Google map with only this or those items selected.

About the modules I'm using: in fact until now I use nothing, this is why I post the question, to know if a module (such gmap or simple Google Maps) is better for doing such kind of stuff.

Comment: Could you list what modules you are using (gmap?)

Comment: In fact until now I use nothing, this is why I post the question, to know if a module (such gmap or simple Google Maps) is better for doing such kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here). That project page also includes various screenshots.

Comment: It's just WON DER FULL !!!!!!!!!

Comment: I m looking for somethink like that from 2 weeks ago with no succes, thank you verry much !   I don't really know why I didn t find this module before, I and I swear that I spend lots of time searching...  Could you please just say with yes or no, if it is possible, when I click on an item from the view list, to get something, like a sliding anchor or just a simple trick to show me the result on the map, maybe another color or just removing all marker from the map or whatever possible

Comment: @snake00jap From your 1st comment it seems that my answer may have helped quite a bit to find the answer. But for the question in your 2nd comment I've to say "I'm not sure". Maybe it's time for you to do some specific experiments, and if needed post a followup question (if you want with a link to this question). PS: "merci" pour l'accept ...